# Testable and self-contained bash script

Tags: bash, sh

I wrote a short bash script for a completion check of downloading images.

**goal of this code (Added)**

I have some downloading content directories. Each of them has a script for downloading images(`tmp.sh`), for example, the following one:

```sh
wget -nc ¥
  http://www.example.com/001.jpg ¥
  http://www.example.com/002.jpg ¥
  ...
  http://www.example.com/123.jpg ¥
```

I want to know which wget completes downloading all or failed.

If you have any good ideas, please tell me them. Thank you.

**done.sh**

````sh
#!/bin/sh

# if a directory name is assigned

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then

  a=`ls -1 $1/*.jpg | wc -l`
  b=`grep jpg $1/tmp.sh | wc -l`
  if [ $a = $b ]; then
    echo $1
  fi
  exit
fi

# if some directory names are assigned

if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
  for dir1 in "$@"; do
    ./done.sh $dir1
  done
fi

# if directory names are not assigned

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  ls -d */ | xargs ./done.sh
fi
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Good

- good indentation
- somewhat helpful comments
- good to do the `; then` bit on the same line as the `if`

## Suggestions

- use double brackets for conditionals
- try shellcheck (It will tell you to put quotes around your variable substitutions.)
- put your arguments into named variables so you don't keep have to referring to `$1`
- put the 3 sections into `if`...`elif`...`else` structure to make clear that you're only going to go into one of them
- check for the existance of `./done.sh` at the beginning
- explain what the goal of the script is somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions. I forgot the programming fundamental techniques in shell programming. I'll correct my code and paste it below the original code.

Comment: @HaruoWakakusa  You may want to read [What I can and cannot do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/71574) before you do that.  As it is one of the things that you can't do under this site's rules.

Comment: Yes, I'll add only the purpose of this code.